# How to add Submenus in a Menu

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

How does one make submenu's in WPF and are their ways to orientate the layout?

Answer (score 18):

For submenus you can add as many MenuItem nested inside.

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem Header="File">
     <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
     <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Header="Edit">
     <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
     <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Header="Options"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just redefine the `ItemsPanel`:

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Menu.ItemsPanel>
  <MenuItem Header="Foo"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Bar"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Baz"/>
  ...
</Menu>
```

Note that this will not get rid of the vertical gradient effect in Vista/Win7 menus. If you want that, set `Menu.Background` property to whatever you want (could even be `Transparent`).